# TableLayoutPanel: Can I divide controls evenly on a form like a grid?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am trying to design a gui and i want to be able to add controls to a table layout panel evenly spaced automatically in a grid like fashion. The amount of controls added dynamic so i need it to be accomplished all during runtime. Basically like cutting a pie...So for example if i have 2 controls one control would take up half the screen on the left and the other half the screen on the right. If I have 4 controls it would be 2 on top and 2 on bottom. Basically dividing the screen up...does anybody know how to accomplish this? Maybe a table layout panel is not the best solution.

Thanks

Comment: What happens for 3 controls? Do you leave a quarter of the screen blank with 2x2 or do you make a 1x3? Extrapolate this to more controls, you need a plan first how this is supposed to be looking.

Comment: Good question. I guess if I have 3 controls it still would be divided into 4 and one of the panels would be empty.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question.  A `TableLayoutPanel` will handle the display fine but it's not magic.  It will just do what you tell it to do.  It's up to you to determine what to tell it to do and that requires some logic and mathematics.  How would you work out the layout if you had to draw blocks on a page?  How would you determine how many rows and how many columns to use?  Whatever logic you would employ for that is exactly the same as the logic you need to employ in your code.  Work out the logic first and then try to write code to implement it.